# Match string which contains anything besides urls?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have mined some data from social media and will have some people read and manually classify them based on stuff. I need to remove all strings which contain ONLY URLs. The problem is that some strings have two or more URls and I really do suck at RegEx. I can match it when there is only one single URL, but not when they have more (in a generic way, since I don't know how many they might have beforehand)

Basicaly I need the following matches:

```
"https://example.net/abc1def" -> true

"foo bar! https://www.example.com/adsdfsdf" -> false

"https://example.com/abc1def http://www.example.org/abc2def" -> true

"foo bar is awesome! https://example.org/abc1def https://www.example.com/abc2def" -> false
```

I do know I can split the string on white spaces and run a single URL match for each position in the array, so I can check if at least any item in the array is not a single URL. But I'd like to know if I can do this directly in a single RegEx on a single string (because there is a huge amount of data).

Comment: What would be your input data and how would you want your output to look like? i.e. is your input data one giant string? Is it an array of strings? Is it a list of strings? Do you want your output to be a 2d array with one dimension being the string and the other a true or false Boolean?

Comment: There is probably a far better way of doing this earlier, or avoiding it entirely, earlier in your program. Could you provide some more detail and context?

Comment: Another idea to match the lines that only contain space/tab and `http://nonspace` can be something like  [`(?i)^[ \t]*(?:https?://\S+[ \t]*)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/WySReW/1).

Comment: @AlexanderCécile thanks for the input. The problem is I already have the dataset in this format, recollecting it would not be feasible right now

Comment: @Delta Ah that’s unfortunate! Best of luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can take anything following `'https://'` is a url:

```
def is_all_urls(s):
    return all(x.startswith('https://') for x in s.split())
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> is_all_urls('foo bar! https://www.example.com/adsdfsdf')
False
>>> is_all_urls('https://example.net/abc1def')
True
```

Comment: Well, I guess this should be the best way to do it. I was just thinking that maybe if I could do this with one single regex search for each entire string, performance would be better (I have millions of strings). But I don't actually know if it would be faster/less intensive, it was just a wild guess.

Comment: @Delta Will the URLs always be separated by a space?

Answer (score 1):

I think this code can be a solution to your problem. The idea is to find the url patterns in the given string and replace them with '', now if your string has some other substring which is not an url then return False else return True.

**Code:**

```
import re

def find_if_url(string): 
    # Find and replace url patterns with ''
    url = re.sub(
        'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]| [!*\(\), ]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+',
        '', string
    ).strip()

    return False if url else True



data = [
    "https://example.net/abc1def",
    "foo bar! https://www.example.com/adsdfsdf",
    "https://example.com/abc1def http://www.example.org/abc2def",
    "foo bar is awesome! https://example.org/abc1def https://www.example.com/abc2def",
    "https://example.org/abc1def foo bar!",
    "https://example.org/abc1def foo bar is awesome! https://example.org/abc1def",
    "https://example.org/abc1def https://www.example.com/abc2def"
]


for string in data:
    print(find_if_url(string))
```

**Result:**

```
FW:~ rameshrv$ python3 /Users/rameshrv/Documents/python/test1.py
True
False
True
False
False
False
True
```

Comment: @Delta Can you supply some more test data. Or please verify the patterns in the data i supplied to test the above code.